# How to dowload Wikileaks Cable Leaks documents as text corpus?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, mongodb

I'd like to perform NLP analysis on Wikileaks US Diplomatic Cable Leaks documents (https://wikileaks.org/plusd/), preferably as Python's NLTK3 corpus od Mongo DB documents. I couldn't find any option for download these in any raw text format, so I'm afraid I'm forced to apply some kind of scraping I guess, but I'd be thankful if anyone would give a clue for some simpler solution, if exists any.